# jquery add attribute to element stored in a variable after initialisation before appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

In my current solution I define an element then parse several `if()` statements that I use to add properties to the element. I know the order of create, appendTo, add attribute is incorrect. So what are some alternatives

Current solution that works, adding `attr` after creation
initialise->appendTo->add attr

```
var myElement=$('<img />',
                    {
                        id:'myId',
                    })

$("#myDiv").append(myElement);


if(myVar === "val1"){
     $("#myId").attr("src","img/img_01.png");
     $("#myId").attr("title","Platform");
}
if(myVar === "val2"){
         $("#myId").attr("src","img/img_02.png");
         $("#myId").attr("title","Speaker");
    }
```

Does not work, create->add attr->appendTo

```
 var myElement=$('<img />',
                    {
                        id:'myId',
                    })

if(myVar === "val1"){
     $("#myId").attr("src","img/img_01.png");
     $("#myId").attr("title","Platform");
}
if(myVar === "val2"){
         $("#myId").attr("src","img/img_02.png");
         $("#myId").attr("title","Speaker");
    }
$("#myDiv").append(myElement);
```

Try to add to variable object, does not work

```
var myElement=$('<img />',
                        {
                            id:'myId',
                        })

if(myVar === "val1"){
         myElement["src"]="img/img_01.png";
         myElement["title"]="Platform";
    }

$("#myDiv").append(myElement);
```

Comment: use `myElement` instead of `$("#myId")`

Comment: So, you can't select the element by it's ID until it exists in the DOM in jQuery.  You'd have to look into what methods jQuery has available for element creation.  However in Vanilla JavaScript... `var newImg = document.createElement('img'); newImg.id = "myId"; newImg.src="img/img_01.png"; ...`

Comment: @Sphinx,  thanks for the pointer, very simple. Please add as answer so I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Doug mentioned, you can not select one element by its ID until it exists in the DOM.

For the element you created, you can get the reference, then change its attributes, finally appendTo.

Below is a working sample, the only modification is replace `$('#myID')` with `myElement`.

```js
function testAVal(myVar){
  var myElement=$('<img />',
                      {
                          id:'myId',
                      })

  if(myVar === "val1"){
       myElement.attr("src","img/img_01.png");
       myElement.attr("title","Platform");
  }
  if(myVar === "val2"){
           myElement.attr("src","img/img_02.png");
           myElement.attr("title","Speaker");
      }
  $("#myDiv").append(myElement);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="testAVal('val1')">A- TestVal1</button>
<button onclick="testAVal('val2')">A- TestVal2</button>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your last attempt you were very close.  Change it from:

```
myElement["src"]="img/img_01.png";
```

to:

```
myElement["attr"]("src","img/img_01.png");
```

```js
var myVar = 'val2';
var myElement = $('<img />', {id: 'myId'});
if(myVar === "val1"){
    myElement["attr"]("src","img/img_01.png");
    myElement["attr"]("title","Platform");
}
if(myVar === "val2"){
    myElement["attr"]("src","img/img_02.png");
    myElement["attr"]("title","Speaker");
}

$("#myDiv").append(myElement);
console.log($("#myDiv")[0].outerHTML);




/*
ANOTHER WAY: ........
 var myElement = $('<img />', {
 id: 'myId',
 src: (myVar === "val1") ? "img/img_01.png" : (myVar === "val2") ? "img/img_02.png" : '',
 title: (myVar === "val1") ? "Platform" : (myVar === "val2") ? "Speaker" : ''
 })
 */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to post an alt method and example